# Animate outside android View paddings?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to animate a shaking button. I have the outer LinearLayout with a padding. But when the shaking starts it doesn't show in the padding area. Isn't their a way to force the animation to happen above all views and layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation will only happen inside the parent view according to my understanding. You make try to use the FrameLayout, or replace padding of the parent with margin of the button.